# Why would a UDP Server not need to use thread?

Tags: networking

Can someone please explain me why would a UDP Server not need to use thread and why would a TCP server need to use threads during the client/server communication?

thanks

Comment: There is no relationship between threads and IP protocol type. You can use either threaded or non-threaded to write either a UDP or TCP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood. There is no need for a UDP server to use *more than one thread*, as it only has to deal with one socket. A TCP server has to deal with a socket per connection, and in blocking mode it therefore needs a thread per connection, in addition to the thread dealing with the listening socket.